# CMV app - files not accessible within network; cloudflare & @font-face

Tags: configurable-map-viewer, arcgis-web-appbuilder

I am having a connectivity issue. My network will not allow me to connect to:
1. //cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4js/2.3.12/proj4.js 
2. CSS3114: @font-face failed OpenType embedding permission check. Permission must be Installable

Where can I reference these files within the application? The WAB widgets will not work now.

Comment: I am using this template, https://github.com/tmcgee/cmv-wab-widgets

Answer (score 1):

The issue was resolved by adding mime types .woff and .json to the server.